# Encoding error when opening Markdown file in BrowserWindow (electron)

Tags: markdown, electron

Hi I'm trying to open a markdown file directly in a electron BrowserWindow like this:

```
const BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
export function help() {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    x: 800,
    y: 0,
    closable: true,
    title: 'Help',
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    webPreferences: {
      defaultFontSize: 20,
      defaultMonospaceFontSize: 20
    }
  });
  let options = {
    extraHeaders: 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'
  };
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/help.md`, options);
  win.on('closed', function() {
  });
  return win;
}
```

But the encoding gets messed up.

⌘ becomes âŒ˜ this   becomes that ðŸ¦„ ðŸŒˆ

Has anybody a solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure the Markdown file is encoded as utf-8?

Comment: Yes pretty sure. It looks good in sublime text and says UTF8

Comment: I double checked. It is UTF8